# Testing for a Stream event

Tags: dart

I'm trying to test my "Site" class if it casts an "event" (using the Stream class)

what I have so far:

```
test('position', () {
    Site site = new Site();

    Function func = (bool isNew) {
      expect(isNew, equals(true));
    };

    site.onPositionChange.listen((bool b) {
      func(b); 
    });

    var callback = expectAsync1(func, count: 1);
    new Timer(new Duration(milliseconds: 100), callback);

    site.position = new Position(x: 1.0, y: 2.0);
  });
```

unfortunately it fails with 
"Expectation: Site: position. Test failed: Caught type '(dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '() => void' of 'callback'."

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The callback to a timer doesn't take one argument. I don't know what you want to test, but here is a version where your `func` function is called with `false` from the Timer.

```
var callback = expectAsync0(() => func(false));  // No need for count if it is 1.
new Timer(new Duration(milliseconds: 100), callback);
```